# How to resolve: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, broadcastreceiver, android-appcompat

There are some other articles with same subject, but my case is different.

I am using a **BroadcastReciever** in an **AlarmManager** application. Upon Alarm fire, I am trying to display an **AlertDialog** with custom layout. As the alarm gets fired, I get the following exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Although I am using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` for my whole application.
Here is the `Manifest:`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    >
```

I am specifying this style in my dialog's layout file as well:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#10000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:padding="10dip" >
<TextView/>...
<Button/>...
</LinearLayout>
```

**Furthermore** I am opening the `dialog` form the `onRecive()` method of my `BroadcastReciver` class:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm_running, null);
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(v)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();

        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {  ...   }
        });
        dialog.show();
}
```

**NOTE:** The `onRecieve()` is getting called successfully, but the problem is with displaying **dialog**. Before I also tried a separate `activity` for displaying the dialog but the activity does not start from background when the app is closed.

How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try with this: -  final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())

Comment: Even if you fix that Exception, you'll get another one after, because you cannot show a `Dialog` directly from that `BroadcastReceiver`. Use a `Notification` instead. Part of the reasoning for disallowing `Activity` starts from the background is because users don't want stuff popping up in the middle of their screens when they're doing things. A `Dialog` popping out of nowhere is just as bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcast receiver is the component of your application just like your Activity.
You are trying to show Alert Dialog in receiver which required Theme.AppCompat, but your Broadcast receiver doesn't have that theme.
What you need to do is open an activity on receiving broadcast and show dialog in it like the calling feature. OR use notification manager to show notification with Action buttons.